# How to reset variable values to null on completion of a TestNG Test Class

Tags: java, unit-testing, scope, garbage-collection, testng

I have created some automated tests to test an API using TestNG.

```
public class EndToEndTest {

private ResponseParser response;
private static String sessionId;
private static float cardCharge;

@BeforeClass
public void setUp() {
    baseURI = getUri();
    response = new ResponseParser();

@Test
@Parameters({"login", "username", "password"})
public void testOne(){

//send some test data into API using specific test data parameters

sessionId = response.getSessionId();
cardCharge = response.getCardCharge();

//assertion etc...
  }

@Test
public void testTwo()
Request req = new Request.RequestBuider()
    .withSession(sessionId)
    .withCardCharge(cardCharge)
    .with....etc...
}
```

This test is a template against which I have 10 or so individual testng xml files providing individual test data - essentially 10 tests.  I am running the 10 testng xml files using 1 testng suite xml file.

When one 'test' finishes, I want the variables - 'sessionId' etc...to be reset to null.  With the way I am running them, the variable values persist between the @Tests (desirable) but also at the class level, presumably because the way I am running with a suite, they remain in scope and not eligible for GC.

Is there a more elegant/robust solution than simply resetting each to null, for example in an @AfterClass method?

```
@AfterClass
public void tearDown(){

sessionId = null;
.....
 }
```

Comment: Why do your data members need to be static in nature ? If you merely convert them into instance variables, then you should be able to get this automatically no? Having test methods depend on static data member prevents you from running your tests in a parallel mode. Would that work ?

Comment: they are static because I wish to persist the state across the @Test annotated methods - e.g. sessionId value needs to be used across several tests.  Perhaps static is easier that using getters and setters? Perhaps testng persists the variable values anyway so I can use local variables?

Comment: If you would like to have them persisted across tests within a <test> tag, then why not persist it as an attribute of ITestContext (which represents a <test> tag) using "Reporter.getCurrentTestResult().getTestContext().setAttribute();" from within a @Test method. Would that work ?

Comment: this is a solution I had not considered, but I have already achieved persistence of state by using static variables whose values are shared at class level. I'm not sure why setting them as static in this context (a testing framework) is a bad thing?

Comment: I was basically only hinting at the fact that "statics" are generally considered evil. Especially if your test class has multiple test methods that aspire to run in parallel, then there can be a chance of race condition with respect to the static data. But if your tests have been designed such that this is not going to be happen, then you can continue using it.

Comment: got you - thanks. I actually need to persist the variable states from one <test> method to the next as they are chained and meant to be run in an end to end fashion. I think I have enough to re-model them now.

Answer (score 0):

yes, there is another way to perform this. You can override the @Test class and manipulate its behavior where u can set a default value for every variable being used. 
please refer ;
http://www.javatpoint.com/custom-annotation

Answer (score -1):

Did you have a look to the `@BeforeTest` and `@AfterTest`annotations? 
See [TestNg documentation][1]
http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html

Comment: yes, thank you, but I don't wish to do this at Test level. I know where and how, in @AfterClass I just want to know if there's a better way.